# Can King take piece end up threatened?

Tags: checkmate

In this position black queen defended by pawn checked white king. Is it possible if the white king take black queen and end up threatened by black pawn?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Assume the image was taken from Black's side (otherwise the queen is not protected).

No. The Black queen is protected by the black pawn, and thus can't be taken by the White king. The only possible move is to move the king to the other direction one square.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much for the answer, Sir. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @DennisvanHemmend If you have no question, please consider to accept the answer. No need to say thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, in chess, the aim is to capture the enemy king and not to have your own king captured.

This means that after you make a move your king must not be attacked (=in check), as otherwise your opponent could capture it. If it is not possible to do this, i.e. if for any move your king ends up being in check, the game is over and the game is either check-mate (if your king is attacked in the original position) or stalemate (if your king is not attacked in the original position.

Specifically for your example, the only way to get out of check is to move the king one step to the left (to the square which should be f1, but is c8 here; see below). It is not possible to take the queen because your king would end up in check after that move.

PS: The board is incorrectly set up. At the start of the game, the white pieces should be on the 1st and 2nd row, and the black pieces on the 7th and 8th row.